# how to use more than one variable in a group array?

Tags: php

I currently have the following code, it works great, but I've never tried to do anything more complex with this sort of thing. I'm wondering how I can add more variables to my result output.

```
$check_alt_sizes = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT model, version, size, category FROM items WHERE model = '$model' AND size != '$category' AND id != '$item_id'");
 if (mysqli_num_rows($check_alt_sizes) >= 1) {
            $group = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_alt_sizes)) {
                $group[ $row['category'] ][] = $row;
        }
```

then later

```
            foreach ($group as $sizes => $alt_size_urls) {
                    foreach ($alt_size_urls as $alt__size_url) {
                        echo "<a href='/items/"; echo "$alt_size_url[slug]"; // slug set elsewhere
                        echo "'>";
                        echo "$sizes</a>";
                    }
                }
        }
```

Now the $sizes part displays a list of sizes that I have gotten from grabbing $row['category'] in the initial $group from the query. What I would like to know is, how can I add more variables to this group, I've only ever dealt with doing it this way, never expanding it.

Currently it displays

```
Alternate Sizes:
       size1
       size2
```

but I would like to be able to add version as well, such as

```
Alternate Sizes:
       Version1 - size1
       Version2 - size1
       Version3 - size2
```

I tried doing this:

```
echo $row['version']; echo "$sizes</a></p></li>";
```

But that just uses the first version found and applies it to every item. obviously because $sizes is looping and the version echo is not. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I modified your source code with this one:

```
$group_size = "";
foreach ($group as $sizes => $alt_size_urls) {
    $group_size .= "Alternate Sizes: <br>";
    $ctr = 0;
    foreach ($alt_size_urls as $alt__size_url) {     
        $group_size .= "<a href='/items/' " . $alt_size_url[slug] . (++$ctr) . "'>" . $sizes . "</a><br>";
    }

}
echo $group_size;
```